# What happens if you let Leo go?

Tags: a-way-out

[Spoilers heavy question]

After the betrayal, Leo leaves in a boat. A pursuit ensues where Vincent shoots at Leo's boat to destroy it.

But if you never shoot it, what happens?

Or what would be a better question: What are the possible outcomes to the boat chase at the end of the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, in my playthrough Leo and Vincent ended up in a fist fight after the boat chase, on a pier or similar surface. Both become more and more injured during the fighting, so eventually the fight ended with one of them defeated.

We didn't stop fighting just to see what happens when you let the game decide the outcome, but I think it would end with either of them winning anyway.